# How to use jQuery grid plugin in Java/JSP?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jqgrid

I want to use [jQuery grid plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) in Java/JSP. The [demo code](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) is given in PHP. Is it possible to convert that into Java/JSP code? I am not getting the correct format when I load from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with Google gson library : http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter writer        = response.getWriter();
    List<MyObject> objectList = service.getListFromDataBase();
    String jsonList           = new Gson().toJson(objectList);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    writer.write(jsonList);
}
```

Comment: This solution works. After i replaced the bellow values      jsonList= jsonList.replaceAll(",\"",",");
     jsonList= jsonList.replaceAll("\":",":");
     jsonList= jsonList.replaceAll("\\{\"","\\{");

Answer (score 0):

You can find in the demo, that a php page returns data in xml format. You can implement such behaviour (connect to db, select information and process it into xml format) in your servlet. Then write it into output stream in servlet and enjoy.

Comment: i retrieved all the data. I'm getting problem in assigning the data.

Comment: my code is `code`<% 
  rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM invheader);
  JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();     
  while(rs.next())       
  {  
   JSONObject cell=new JSONObject();
   cell.put("id",rs.getInt(1));            
   cell.put("invdate",rs.getString(2));            
   cell.put("name",rs.getString(3)); 
   cell.put("note",rs.getDouble(4));
   cell.put("tax",rs.getDouble(5));
   cell.put("total",rs.getDouble(6));
   cellarray.add(cell);

  }    
  
  System.out.println("Response Data : "+cellarray);
 %>`code`

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert your php code to jsp, directly you can use your gird in your jsp with your own sytle(css). for that have to design your gird elements,i mean how many coloumns that has presented in your gird, for that write your grid format and just use that grid format in current jsp, and write your business logic in servlet like,

```
String caption = "MyGrid";
String colHeader = "S.No,col1,col2,col3";
String colName = "S.No,col1,col2,col3";
String align = "center,left,left,left";
String widths = "25,25,25,25";


<jsp:include page='Grid.jsp' >
 <jsp:param name='caption' value='<%=caption%>' />
 <jsp:param name='url' value='<%=request.getContextPath() + "/ProgrammeGridServlet" %>' />
 <jsp:param name='colHeader' value='<%=colHeader%>' />
 <jsp:param name='colName' value='<%=colName%>' />
 <jsp:param name='aling' value='<%=align%>' />
 <jsp:param name='width' value='<%=widths%>' />
 </jsp:include>
```

here the url parameter value that prints output of your servlet

Comment: His problem is obtaining the data from the DB to fill the grid. This can't be done in HTML/CSS/JS. The solution is however easy (just a servlet), but it's not clear what format exactly he want to get the data in (JSON or XML or whatever).